# User-defined amount of dynamically created controls in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamically-generated

My program is currently set up to just add one row of controls below the original. How can I make it so the user can add as many lines of controls as they would like?

```
private void surfaceAddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        //Adds new set of controls on button click
        for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++)
        {

            ComboBox surfaceCombo2 = new ComboBox();
            TextBox sideWallsText2 = new TextBox();
            TextBox backWallsText2 = new TextBox();
            TextBox floorText2 = new TextBox();
            Label newLabel = new Label();
            Label newLabel2 = new Label();
            Label newLabel3 = new Label();

            Absorption_Coefficients alpha = new Absorption_Coefficients(); //Adds surfaces to combobox
            List<string> materialslist = alpha.listLoad();
            materialslist.Sort();
            surfaceCombo2.Items.AddRange(materialslist.ToArray());
            surfaceCombo2.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;

            //Sets locations and sizes of new row of options, then displays them
            surfaceCombo2.Location = new Point(1, 150 * i + 30);               
            sideWallsText2.Location = new Point(393, 153 * i + 30);
            backWallsText2.Location = new Point(561, 153 * i + 30);
            floorText2.Location = new Point(711, 153 * i + 30);
            newLabel.Location = new Point(321, 158 * i + 30);
            newLabel2.Location = new Point(439, 158 * i + 30);
            newLabel3.Location = new Point(609, 158 * i + 30);
            surfaceCombo2.Width = 322;
            sideWallsText2.Width = 43;
            backWallsText2.Width = 43;
            floorText2.Width = 43;
            newLabel.Text = "Side Walls, ft²";
            newLabel2.Width = 120;
            newLabel2.Text = "Back/or Front Walls, ft²";
            newLabel3.Text = "Floor/or Ceiling, ft²";

            this.Controls.Add(surfaceCombo2);
            this.Controls.Add(sideWallsText2);
            this.Controls.Add(backWallsText2);
            this.Controls.Add(floorText2);
            this.Controls.Add(newLabel);
            this.Controls.Add(newLabel2);
            this.Controls.Add(newLabel3);

            this.Size = new Size(769, 209 * i + 30); //Increases form to accomodate new controls
        }
    }
```

This is the form with just the one surface added. I want to make it so there is a new row underneath each time the user clicks +Surface.

[image: The Form with one surface added]

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Consider setting the repeating bottom up in a Gridview or something to handle the one to many with scrolling support

Comment: I tried making a list of comboboxes that adds a new one each time, but I don't know how to rename new elements it adds based on the iteration of button clicks.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++)
```

Instesd of 2 in for loop, replace with n, where n will be number gathered from some control

Answer (score 0):

First step is to take your existing code and create a method that creates a row.  Ideally as part of this step, you create a custom control that encapsulates much of the logic you already have now.

Second step is to take that new method and require a parameter `numberOfRows`, use that parameter, and default it to 1.  Then make sure it still works.

Final step is to provide a method for the user to input `numberOfRows` and send that to your method.